# Log4j file not excluded from Maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have a log4j.xml file in src/main/resources that I'm trying to exclude from the jar file.  I have a property with version 3.0.0 in the parent pom file.

```
...
       <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
...
```

Comment: What is `exclcudes`?? And what exactly is the error or problem?

Comment: @manouti, the problem is that the file is not getting excluded from the jar file.  I corrected the spelling but am still having the same issue.

Comment: First if you don't like to have the file into your jar simply remove it from `src/main/resources` cause that's the convention in Maven that everything in `src/main` is packaged. If you only need it for testing move it into `src/test/resources`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to version 3.0.0 of the maven-jar-plugin and also changed the exclude back to "**/log4j.xml" from "src/main/resources/log4j.xml", which I had temporarily switched it to, so I'm not sure if one ore both fixes were required.

Answer (score 1):

According to maven manual (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html), you have to put the files to include/exclude in `resources` section. So, if the file is located on src/resources, the configuration will be:

```
<project>
...
<name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
...
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
    ...
  </resources>
...
</build>
...
</project>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will not work cause the location for resources is `src/main/resources` and not `src/resources`. And as always you should follow the conventions in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<exclude>**/*log4j*</exclude>` It should work if this pattern is acceptable for you.

Note what's written at the bottom of the doc: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

*Note that the patterns need to be relative to the path specified for the plugin's classesDirectory parameter.*